# spring security get user id from DB

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, authentication, spring-security

I am using spring security for authentication and successfully able to get `User` object (`org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User`) anywhere I need.

But I want `UserId` also, which is not there in spring's `User` object. So I create my own object(`com.app.site.pojo.User`). It has few additional variables like *userId*,*user date of birth* etc. Now I want spring security to use my `user` object instead of spring `User` object. and it should have all the details about that user.

I tried to type cast the user object to my object, it is throwing exception (It is obvious).

I dont want to make DB call again to get the userId from DB again.

**How can I achieve it?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was in the same situation as you, what I did was redirect the user to a new page after login, and create a controller function of that page, to get the user from DB and store his *id* as a *Session Variable*.

```
    @RequestMapping(value = { "/overview" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView overViewPage(HttpServletRequest request) {

        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
        model.addObject("title", "Spring Security + Hibernate Example");
        model.addObject("message", "This is default page!");
        model.setViewName("hello");


        Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        UserDetails userDetail = (UserDetails) auth.getPrincipal();

        User u = userService.getUser(userDetail.getUsername());
        request.getSession().setAttribute("userId", u.getId());

        return model;

    }
```

You can use the user object or just use his *id* for future queries by doing

```
int userId = (int) request.getSession().getAttribute("userId");
```

My *userService* is just a simple service

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import com.sports.dao.UserDao;

@Service
@Transactional
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService{

    @Autowired
    private UserDao userDao;

    public com.sports.models.User getUser(String username){
        return userDao.findByUserName(username);
    }

}
```

I'm also new to spring so I'm not sure if this is the best way to do it.

Answer (score 6):

A better way of doing this is to create a UserDetaisService that returns an object that extends your type of Object and implements UserDetails. This means you only need to perform one database lookup.

By having the result of loadUserByUsername implement UserDetails and extend your User object, you can refer to it as the custom user object and Spring Security can refer to it as a UserDetails.

For example:

```
@Service
public class UserRepositoryUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {
    private final UserRepository userRepository;

    @Autowired
    public UserRepositoryUserDetailsService(UserRepository userRepository) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
    }

    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username)
            throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        User user = userRepository.findByEmail(username);
        if(user == null) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Could not find user " + username);
        }
        return new UserRepositoryUserDetails(user);
    }

    private final static class UserRepositoryUserDetails extends User implements UserDetails {

        private UserRepositoryUserDetails(User user) {
            super(user);
        }

        @Override
        public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
            return AuthorityUtils.createAuthorityList("ROLE_USER");
        }

        @Override
        public String getUsername() {
            return getEmail();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isEnabled() {
            return true;
        }

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 5639683223516504866L;
    }
}
```

You can then refer to the custom UserDetailsService in your configuration. For example:

```
<security:authentication-manager>
  <security:authentication-provider user-service-ref="customUserDetails" />
</security:authentication-manager>
<bean id="customUserDetails" class="sample.UserRepositoryUserDetailsService"/>
```

If you are using Spring Security 3.2.x+ you can use Spring Security's [@AuthenticationPrincipal](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.x/reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-authentication-principal) to resolve the custom user object. For example:

```
@RequestMapping("/messages/inbox")
public ModelAndView findMessagesForUser(@AuthenticationPrincipal CustomUser customUser) {

    // .. find messags for this user and return them ...
}
```

Otherwise you can use the following:

```
@RequestMapping("/messages/inbox")
public ModelAndView findMessagesForUser(Authentication auth) {
        User customUser = (User) auth.getPrincipal();
     ...
}
```

If using the XML configuration, you will need to register AuthenticationPrincipalArgumentResolver with Spring MVC.

```
<mvc:annotation-driven>
  <mvc:argument-resolvers>
    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.security.web.bind.support.AuthenticationPrincipalArgumentResolver"/>
  </mvc:argument-resolvers>
</mvc:annotation-driven>
```

You can find details about this in my [github sample project](https://github.com/rwinch/gs-spring-security-3.2/). The README also reference [the recorded webinar](https://spring.io/blog/2014/01/21/webinar-replay-spring-security-3-2).

Comment: I can't get this to work. My CustomUser in the view method is null. If I use UserDetails it works but I need a CustomUser instance. I'm using Spring Security 4.0.1.RELEASE

Comment: Fixed: This was because my OAuth config was using my user repository but the WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter defined inMemoryAuthentication for my tests.

Answer (score 0):

```
<bean id="daoAuthenticationProvider" class="org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider">
  <property name="userDetailsService" ref="customUserDetailsService" />
</bean>
```

customUserDetailsService will override loadUserByUsername like below

```
@Override
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) {
return customUser;
// where customUser extends org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User
}
```

You can have custom fields under customUser

Comment: It will better if we can do something using annotation and If you can provide me some example that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

```
@RequestMapping(value="/getLogedUserid")
public Long getUserByUsername(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest) {      
    HttpSession httpSession = httpServletRequest.getSession();
    SecurityContext securityContext = (SecurityContext)
            httpSession.getAttribute("SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT");
    String username = securityContext.getAuthentication().getName();
    return userMetier.getUserByUsername(username);
}
```

here we have the definition of the function getting the id by the username

```
    @Override
public Long getUserByUsername(String Username) {
    User user = userRepository.getUserByUsername(Username);

    return user.getIdUser();
}
```