# Spring - Many To One - phonebook assigning contacts to user

Tags: spring

I am a newbee in java and spring. My first exercise is project to simulate web phone book.  I'm stuck with assigning contact to specific user, and later on displaying contacts for that specific user. Any idea or guideline is appreciated.

User class

```
@Entity
public class User implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int id;

private String name;
private String lastName;
private String email;
private String username;
private String password;


@Transient
private String retypePassword;

@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER,cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(name="users_roles",
    joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
    inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name="role_id", referencedColumnName="roles_id")}
)
private List<Rolee> authorities;


@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "userForPhonebook")
@Fetch(value = FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
private Collection<Contact> allContacts;

// getters and setters
```

Contact class

```
@Entity
public class Contact implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int contactID;

private String name;
private String lastName;
private String email;
private String areaCode;
private String telNumber;
private String adress;
private String city;
private String note;
private String contactImage;

@JoinColumn(name = "users_id")
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, optional = false)
private User userForPhonebook;

// getters and setters
```

ContactServiceImpl class

```
@Service
public class ContactServiceImpl implements ContactService {

@Autowired
private ContactDAO contactDAO;

@Autowired
private UserDAO userDAO;

@Autowired
private ServletContext context;

@Override
public void addContact(ContactModel contactModel, MultipartFile[] contactImages, User user) {

    Contact contact = new Contact();

    /*
    creating contact
    */ 

    User user2 = userDAO.userGetById(user.getId()); //<-- i cant get user id
    contact.setUserForPhonebook(user2);

    // --------------------------------

    User u = new User();                //
    u.setId(2);                         // hard coding users id... 
    contact.setUserForPhonebook(u);     // and its working fine

   //  rest of code to create contact ...
```

UserDAOImpl

```
// ...
@Override
public void addUser(User user) {

    Session s = getCurrentSession();
    Transaction trans = s.beginTransaction();
    getCurrentSession().save(user);
    trans.commit();

}
// ...
```

UserServiceImpl

```
// ...
@Override
public void addUser(UserModel userModel) {

    User user = new User();

    // creating user ...

    getUserDAO().addUser(user);
}
// ...
```

RegisterController

```
// ...
@RequestMapping(value = "/addUser", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String postRegister(@Valid @ModelAttribute("newUser") UserModel userModel, BindingResult results, ModelMap model) {

    if (results.hasErrors()) {
        return "addUser";
    }

    // checking if username, email exist in database ... 
    // password matching


    getUserService().addUser(user);

    return "index";
}
// ...
```

ContactController

```
// ...
@RequestMapping(value = "/addContact", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String postAddContact(@Valid @ModelAttribute("addContact") ContactModel contactModel, BindingResult results, HttpServletRequest request, @RequestParam("contactImages") MultipartFile[] contactImages, User user)
        throws FileNotFoundException, IOException  {

    if (results.hasErrors()) {
        return "addContact";
    }

    getContactService().addContact(contactModel, contactImages, user);

    return "redirect:phoneBook";
}
//...
```

Comment: When you save your users, are you updating your local objects ? Like `user = userDao.save(user);` or `int id = userDao.save(user); user.setId(id);` before sending them to `addContact`?. It would be nice to have a usage example in your controllers.

Comment: I was trying also with active user with get.Principal, but i cant cast it to my user. I know principal is generally for username and password, but i had to try :)

Comment: Saying "I'm stuck" and posting a wall of code isn't really clear. What is the concrete problem you're facing?

Comment: @JBNizet I'm trying to bind contact to user when user adding new contact, so when phone book is opened it displays only contacts for specific user

Answer (score 0):

You are not specifying how Spring is supposed to bind your `User` object in your `postAddContact` signature.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/addContact", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String postAddContact(
        // Ok, this is a model retrieved from request params
        @Valid @ModelAttribute("addContact") ContactModel contactModel,

        // Ok, a BindingResult is mapped when the validation above occurs
        BindingResult results,

        // Ok, bind the internal HttlServletRequest
        HttpServletRequest request,

        // Ok, bind this to the multipart part of the request
        @RequestParam("contactImages") MultipartFile[] contactImages,

        // ... no idea how to bind this
        User user)

        throws FileNotFoundException, IOException  {
    // ...
}
```

You need to specify yourself which user is going to get the contact.

You could add the field inside your `ContactModel` object, like `userId`, and in your controller retrieve that user from database before adding the contact.

**ContactController.java**

```
// ...
@RequestMapping(value = "/addContact", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String postAddContact(@Valid @ModelAttribute("addContact") ContactModel contactModel, BindingResult results, HttpServletRequest request, @RequestParam("contactImages") MultipartFile[] contactImages)
        throws FileNotFoundException, IOException  {

    if (results.hasErrors()) {
        return "addContact";
    }

    // Retrieve the user
    User user = getUserService().retrieveUser(contactModel.getUserId());

    getContactService().addContact(contactModel, contactImages, user);

    return "redirect:phoneBook";
}
//...
```

You could also add a path variable, use the connected user, etc. Above code is just a suggestion.

Comment: Thank you kagmole for answering. I tried yours suggestion, but I’m always getting 0(zero) for    userId after creating contact in DB. I think my method    getUserById don’t get correct userId, because in debug userId is always 0. I’m going to see why is that happening.

Answer (score 0):

The answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29327159/spring-security-get-user-id-from-db?answertab=votes#tab-top) helped me to assign currently active user to contact and my postAddContact looks like this. Sorry if I didn't correctly ask the question and I hope this will help someone else

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/addContact", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String postAddContact(@Valid @ModelAttribute("addContact") ContactModel contactModel, BindingResult results, HttpServletRequest request, @RequestParam("contactImages") MultipartFile[] contactImages)
        throws FileNotFoundException, IOException  {

    if (results.hasErrors()) {
        return "addContact";
    }

    Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    UserDetails userDetail = (UserDetails) auth.getPrincipal();

    User u = userDAO.getUserByUsername(userDetail.getUsername());
    request.getSession().setAttribute("id", u.getId());

    int userId = (int) request.getSession().getAttribute("id");

    User user = new User();
    user.setId(userId);


    getContactService().addContact(contactModel, contactImages, user);

    return "redirect:phoneBook";
}
```